# Load blank redirect component into Iframe Angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular

My app comprises of the setup:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

All works fine but at some point, I use an Iframe that loads in a page from another website, once the user fills out details, a component is loaded in, that redirects the user accordingly

The redirect works but for a split second I can see the header and footer within the Iframe, so I'm getting something like:

```
 <app-header></app-header>
    <router-outlet>
<iFrame>
      <app-header></app-header>
      <app-redirects><app-redirects>
      <app-footer></app-footer>
 </iFrame>
    </router-outlet>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
```

When all I want to see is a blank page

I tried to add a div to the html of the app-redirects which hides everything, including header and footer which works, but you still see the header and footer just for a moment and then nothing

Comment: I think we're missing a lot of detail to effectively answer the question.  The page in the IFRAME does the redirect?  Does it redirect the whole page, or just the content in the IFRAME?  How does the "redirect" work?

Comment: show the redirect code? What is the url used for iFrame?

Comment: Hi sorry didn't add redirect code because all of that works fine, it basically uses window.top to take the user out of IFrame and onto another page, this question is, I think, to do with aesthetics, is there a way for me to load in the component without, or to hide the header and footer?